# How to replace a column using pandas with the matching value from another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have an excel sheet with following columns.

```
Date, Ship-to-party ,Volume
1/09/2019 PQ01    1000
2/09/2019 PQXC    2500
...
```

Another sheet is like;

```
Document Date Deliveryid Sales
01/09/2019    153678     350
01/09/2019    236742     400
```

Another sheet is like;

```
Time        Site    Dips
01/09/2019  SiteA   1500
01/09/2019  SiteB   1222
...
```

In another excel/csv file I have defined what Ship-to party means.
That is, I have originally 3 different work sheets, each contain a column (eg: sitename) in different names. (eg: SHip-to party,Sitename,Deliveryid)
My requirement is to combine all 3 worksheets in a single sheet based on date and sitename along with other values.
 To do that, I have a seperate sheet which contain what ship-to-party value=Sitename=Deliveryid ( 3 columns are there)

How can I replace original 3 worksheets columns based on a single sitename and combine them to get a single excel sheet using pandas?

My mapping sheet contain

```
ship-to party  Sitename  Deliveryid

PQ01           SiteA      543892
PQXY           SiteB      539081
....
```

I expect my final sheet is like

```
Date       Sitename  Sales Dips Volume
1/09/2019   SiteA    500   1000 1500
1/09/2019   SiteB    100   500  2000
....
```

I try like as Hue mentioned;

```
def write_dips(writer):
    file_path = '/Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/DataLoader/output.xlsx'
    mappingfilepath ='/Users/ratha/PycharmProjects/DataLoader/data/mappings/File Mapping.csv'

    df_dips = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='DipsSummary')
    df_sales = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='SaleSummary')
    df_delivery = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='DeliverySummary')
    df_mapping = pd.read_csv(mappingfilepath, delimiter=',', skiprows=[1])
    df2 = df_dips.merge(df_mapping, left_on='Site',right_on='SHIP TO NAME').\
        merge(df_sales,left_on ='Delivery ID',right_on='Deliveryid').\
        merge(df_delivery, left_on='SHIP-TO PARTY',right_on='Ship-To Party')

    print(df2.dtypes) <--this prints all columns..so merging works
    x = df2.groupby(['Dip Time', 'Site', 'Tank ID', 'Product', 'Volume',
                'IdassId', 'TankNo', 'GradeNo','Sales','Ship-To Party', 'Material','Qty in Stock UoM'], as_index=False).apply(atg_aggregation)
    x.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='DipsNewSummary')
```

But final output file doesnt contain anything.The groupby I try is right ( I use group by for all columns presents in all 3 sheets?

After merging I expect my sheet should be like; ( I expect to pick few columns in all 3 sheets, so applying all the columns in groupby method)

```
Dip Time  Site  Tank ID Product Dips DeliveryId Sales Ship-To Party 
1/09/2019 SiteA  1      Diesel  500  526781     150   PQ01
```

Comment: df.merge()? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html

Comment: @Aryerez the issue here  is to use merge() function is, My column names are not matching. And column contents too. please check my above example i provided as 3 sheets.(Ship-to-party, delivery id,site all 3 columns mean one. the mapping info is in another file)

Comment: Have you tried using the `left_on`, `right_on` parameters of the `merge` function, as in the reference I've added? And if you mean by "column contents not matching" that there is no unique key to merge on, it sounds like you can't do it by hand, so how could you expect python to do it?

Comment: @Aryerez I got your point. but there is another seperate file which contain matching info. How can i combine that with existing 3 sheets and make a masterlist of that is my original question.. make some sense?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Your ship-to-party column has strings in it and your delivery id column has numbers in it. How can that be combined? I think your question is not clear. Do you want to combine all the three sheets on date column?

Comment: @Hue I have edited my quetsion by providing mapping sheet info. Yes I want to combine all 3 sheets into one sheet based on date/site along with other column values. If you see there is no common site column. For that I have to use that mapping info sheet

Comment: @Ratha : Based on the mapping info, Create " ship to party column" in the other two sheets ( use map dictionary values for this) and then merge all the sheets on ['ship to party'] and ['Date']

Comment: @Hue Thanks a lot..Any sample code?

Comment: @Ratha: You know what, just merge your mapping info df with the first df. Your first df will  then have the site and deliveryID information. You can then again use the same merge function to merge all the three sheets. This is easy to achieve. Do you need code for this?

Comment: @Hue, yes please need a code sample would be really helpful

Comment: @Hue  I try merging..then it gives error in groupby.Says column not found.. WOuld you please give a sample including with final groupby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to merge the 3 sheets , you just need a merge and not groupby.

Here is the sample code you can try and let me know if it helps.

```
df
Out[29]: 
  ship-to party Sitename  Deliveryid
1          PQ01    SiteA    543892.0
2          PQXY    SiteB    539081.0

df1
Out[30]: 
        Date Ship-to-party  Volume
0  1/09/2019          PQ01  1000.0
1  2/09/2019          PQXC  2500.0

df1=df1.merge(df,left_on='Ship-to-party',right_on='ship-to party')

df1
Out[32]: 
        Date Ship-to-party    ...      Sitename Deliveryid
0  1/09/2019          PQ01    ...         SiteA   543892.0

[1 rows x 6 columns]
df1.columns=['Date', 'Ship-to-party', 'Volume', 'ship-to party', 'Site',
       'Deliveryid']
```

Now merge df1 with other sheets.

```
df1.merge(df2,on='Site').merge(df3,on='Deliveryid')
```

Comment: Thanks Hue..You can see my original quetsion How i try the merge..But why that group by is working as expected?

Comment: what is atg_aggregation? and with group-by, could you please explain what you are trying to do here? Which columns do you want to group on and what aggregate function do you want?

Comment: Aggregation is just counting records based on date columns. using groupby, imtrying to group per day/per site/per tank or product what is sale value, delivery value dips value..my code above looks ok on merge?

Comment: It doesn't look ok. But we can help you, only when you give us a sample of what your merge output looks like and what output you expect to see after groupby.

Comment: I edited my question with how my output has to be..Basically picking few columns in all 3 sheets and making final sheet..Sorry, im totally new to python/panda

Comment: what is the output of df2?

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Dip Time, Site, Tank ID, Product, Volume, totalRecords_x, SHIP-TO PARTY, SHIP TO NAME, SITE NAME, IDASS ID, Date, IdassId, TankNo, GradeNo, Sales, totalRecords_y, Document Date, Ship-To Party, Material, Qty in Stock UoM, totalRecords]
Index: []

Comment: It looks first merge working (it prints data)but not other subsequent merges..the way I merge looks wrong

Comment: I use repetable merge with left-on, right on columns as my mapping sheets column name doesnt match exactly with the orginal 3 worksheets

Comment: Hue thanks a lot, adding how='left' looks working to me. It works with 2nd merge. But for 3 rd merge process getting exit with signal interrupt (looks high processing, anyway that is seperate issue, i need to check why that occurs)Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

Comment: Hue, do you know why this occurs?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077949/dataframe-merge-gives-process-finished-with-exit-code-137-interrupted-by-signa