# Dataframe merge gives `Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm, pandas-groupby

I use dataframe merge 3 times to get my desire results

```py
def write_dips(writer):
    df_dips = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='DipsSummary')
    df_sales = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='SaleSummary')
    df_delivery = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='DeliverySummary')
    df_mapping = pd.read_csv(mappingfilepath, delimiter=',', skiprows=[1])

    df_dips = df_dips.merge(df_mapping, left_on='Site', right_on='SHIP TO NAME',how='left')
    df_dips = df_dips.merge(df_sales, left_on ='IDASS ID', right_on='IdassId',how='left')
    df_dips = df_dips.merge(df_delivery, left_on='SHIP-TO PARTY', right_on='Ship-To Party', how='left')
```

When I try to do 3rd merge option I get following error;

> Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: I guess thats a memory issue the OS is killing the script. Can you take top 6000 rows with `head` or `.iloc` or any small amount of data and try to merge to see if it runs successfully.

Comment: @DataPsycho can this be overcome by setting index? If so, how should I set index  for each dataframe?

Comment: Could it be linked to the fact you skip the first row of your csv file (containing potentially the columns names, that cannot be found later during merge) ?

Comment: @Edel, I tried with SKiprows[0], but then i get it couldn't find a column

Comment: I added at he end with .fillna(0) in each merge fixes memory leak issue

Comment: @Ratha, very interesting ! Can you please post the code line as an answer, and mark it as solved for potential re-users ?

Comment: I had the same problem while merging 16 datasets, and at last, I found that there were lots of duplicates in datasets. So, check if there are duplicates in your datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overcame by using `fillna(0)` at each merge.

```
def write_dips(writer):
    df_dips = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='DipsSummary')
    df_sales = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='SaleSummary')
    df_delivery = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='DeliverySummary')
    df_mapping = pd.read_csv(mappingfilepath, delimiter=',', skiprows=[1])

df_dips = df_dips.merge(df_mapping, left_on='Site', right_on='SHIP TO NAME',how='left').fillna(0)
df_dips = df_dips.merge(df_sales, left_on ='IDASS ID', right_on='IdassId',how='left').fillna(0)
df_dips = df_dips.merge(df_delivery, left_on='SHIP-TO PARTY', right_on='Ship-To Party', how='left').fillna(0)
```